# Python - regex filter to exclude folder for win and linux paths

Tags: python, regex

I have a list with folders and file paths (example for `linux`):

```
res=['./base/folder', './bitbucket ', './output1.txt']
print(res)
```

So I would like to use `filter` and `regex` that will ignore `bitbucket` folder from this list for further processing.
This python script should support paths on both system paths - windows and linux since you are aware of the difference with slashes and backslashes in the paths.

So I made this script but I am not sure if I can define this in one line or multiple lines are needed and how I can support it for both platforms...

```
import re
.........
.........
res=['./base/folder', './bitbucket ', './output1.txt']
extObjs = filter(None, res)
print(extObjs)
extObjs = filter(lambda x: not re.match(r'.*\/bitbucket', x), extObjs)
for e in extObjs:
    print (e)
```

What will be the optimal solution to cover this for both OS paths?
note: must use regex and filter combination

Comment: Maybe adding ``\`` will be enough? `r'.*[/\\]bitbucket'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might write this in one line using [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) matching either `/` or `\` before it using a character class, and not including empty lines in the result.

```
import re

res = ['', '   ', './base/folder', './bitbucket ', './output1.txt', '\\bitbucket']
extObjs = filter(lambda s: s.strip() and not re.search(r"[/\\]bitbucket\b", s), res)

print(list(extObjs))
```

Output

```
['./base/folder', './output1.txt']
```

Answer (score -1):

my suggestion is Check the OS first, before filter the path

```
import platform
import re
system = platform.system()
res=['./base/folder', './bitbucket ', './output1.txt']
extObjs = filter(None, res)
if system == 'Linux':
   extObjs = filter(lambda x: not re.match(r'.*/bitbucket', x), extObjs)
elif system == 'Windows':
   extObjs = filter(lambda x: not re.match(r'.*\bitbucket', x), extObjs)
```

Comment: sorry - for explanation purposes - can you please clarify me how is that for the linux you removed the first backslash. I thought I had to use first backslah anyway for both cases? or otherwise my backslash will be ignored if I do not use escape character? or that is not the case for the regex? (sorry - not a regex expert). Thx

Comment: @AndreyS This is the wrong answer, see the other.